# Please help in correcting the sed command for replacing the strings?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have values defined in the variables like below And trying to replace these values in the file called "server.xml"

port_number=8081 ui_redirectPort=443

Content of the server.xml file is this

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"connectionTimeout="20000"redirectPort="8443"maxParameterCount="1000"/>
```

And the command I used is this.,

```
sed -i "s/<Connector port=\"8080\" protocol=\"HTTP\/1.1\" connectionTimeout=\"20000\" redirectPort=\"8443\" maxParameterCount=\"1000\"/<Connector port=\"$port_number\" protocol=\"HTTP\/1.1\" connectionTimeout=\"20\" redirectPort=\"$ui_redirectPort\" maxParameterCount=\"10\"/g" server.xml
```

I am having issues updating the values. Please help in framing this command?

Command I used.,

```
sed -i "s/<Connector port=\"8080\" protocol=\"HTTP\/1.1\" connectionTimeout=\"20000\" redirectPort=\"8443\" maxParameterCount=\"1000\"/<Connector port=\"$port_number\" protocol=\"HTTP\/1.1\" connectionTimeout=\"20\" redirectPort=\"$ui_redirectPort\" maxParameterCount=\"10\"/g" server.xml
```

Comment: Is the first command you used the same as the second one? If they are, don't write it twice.

Comment: The file doesn't have spaces after all the attributes, but your regexp has spaces there.

Answer (score 1):

Your regexp doesn't match the input because there are differences in whitespace.

Rather than trying to match the whole line, just replace the two attributes.

```
sed -i -e "s/port=\"[0-9]*\"/port=\"$port_number\"/" -e "s/redirectPort=\"[0-9]*\"/redirectPort=\"$ui_redirectPort\"/" server.xml
```